# Class composition confusion

Tags: c++

I am using Code Blocks v16*

I got this error and I cannot figure out what seemed to be the problem:

> Person.cpp:17:62: note:   mismatched types ‘const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>’ and ‘void’
>        std::cout << "Birthdate: " << BirthdateObj.showBirthDate();
>                                                                 ^
>   Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
>   1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))

Here is my simple program:

Person.h

```
#ifndef PERSON_H
#define PERSON_H

#include <Birthdate.h>

class Person
{
    public:
        Person(int age, Birthdate BirthdateObj);
        virtual ~Person();

        void showPersonInformation();

    private:
        int age;
        Birthdate BirthdateObj;
};

#endif // PERSON_H
```

Person.cpp

```
#include "Person.h"
#include <iostream>

Person::Person(int age, Birthdate BirthdateObj) : age(age), BirthdateObj(BirthdateObj)
{
    //ctor
}

Person::~Person()
{
    //dtor
}

void Person::showPersonInformation()
{
    std::cout << "Current age: " << age << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Birthdate: " << BirthdateObj.showBirthDate();
}
```

Birthdate.h

```
#ifndef BIRTHDATE_H
#define BIRTHDATE_H


class Birthdate
{
    public:
        Birthdate(int day, int month, int year);
        virtual ~Birthdate();

        void showBirthDate();

    private:
        int day, month, year;
};

#endif // BIRTHDATE_H
```

Birthdate.cpp

```
#include "Birthdate.h"
#include <iostream>

Birthdate::Birthdate(int day, int month, int year) : day(day), month(month), year(year)
{
    //ctor
}

Birthdate::~Birthdate()
{
    //dtor
}

void Birthdate::showBirthDate()
{
    std::cout << day << "/" << month << "/" << year;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Birthdate.h"
#include "Person.h"

int main()
{

    Birthdate BirthdateObj(7, 16, 1995);
    //Birthdate *pBirthdateObj = &BirthdateObj;

    Person PersonObj(20, BirthdateObj);
    Person *pPersonObj = &PersonObj;

    pPersonObj->showPersonInformation();
    //pBirthdateObj->showBirthDate();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You seem to have a some misunderstandings about how functions and their return values work. Consider picking up a [great book on C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to ensure you're not learning from questionable material.

Comment: BirthdateObj.showBirthDate() returns void which you cannot pass to std::cout. Btw you know you can just call PersonObj.showPersonInformation(), right?

Comment: @stijn Hello, yes I got it now. Anyways for me(just for me or maybe some other people), having pointer to an object and access its member via -> is beautiful lol. Well you could tell me if it is a bad practice or not tho.

Comment: Using raw pointers when not needed is generally already frowned upon. But if the reason is you find them beautiful, it is *definitely* bad practice.

Comment: @stijn Hello there, do you know qt? They do this "QSpinBox *sb = new QSpinBox" I think that is what I was looking for.

Comment: That's why I said 'when not needed'. Qt is special because they heavily rely on a parent-child model for managing ownership of objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your birthday function returns `void` instead of a `string`. As `cout` cannot output `void` to standard output, this is where your error is coming from. Change this line:

```
std::cout << "Birthdate: " << BirthdateObj.showBirthDate();
```

to:

```
std::cout << "Birthdate: ";
BirthdateObj.showBirthDate();
```

Alternatively, you could change the return type of `showBirthdate` to `string` and keep the above line as is.

Comment: Hello thank you so much, I have figured it out now. Does it have any term or not? I will choose your post as an answer.

Comment: What do you mean by *term*?

Comment: @PcAF Is there any way that I do not have to make a class object and just make a pointer out of it?